# derivatives let $f(t) = x^6/100$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm doing the following question

let $f(t) = x^6/100$
find $f^\prime(x)$

is this just asking for the basic derivative of $x^6/100
= 3x^5/50$

or does the $t$ in $f(t)$ imply something else?

Comment: Well, I think it's just a matter of notation. If
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{100}t^6
$$
then of course
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{100}x^6
$$

Comment: @MattiP. The question says that $f(t) = \frac{x^6}{100}$ though -- $t$ isn't mentioned in it.  Likely it's a typo

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should be f(x) = x^6/100 or f(t) =t^6/100. Indeed, f'(x) (sometimes read as "f prime of x") does denote the derivative of f(x).

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a typo, then $f'(x)=0$ because the variables are independent. However, it is probably a typo, because else the question is too easy. In this case, $f'(x)=\frac{3x^5}{50}$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(t)=\frac{1}{100}x^6$ then $f$ does not depend on the variable $t$. Hence differentiation with respect to $t$ gives $f'(t)=0.$

Comment: But the OP says that differentiation is with respect to $x$....

Comment: Technically, this is true. But you should also remember the nature of this site and it should occur to you that maybe this is the result of a typo rather than the actual, intended problem. To me, that seems like the most probable resolution by far. This site isn't about solving problems, it's about helping people. And in this case, the difference between the two buttons is larger than most.